# UK Traffic Cameras

Tags: united-kingdom, traffic

I have seen traffic cameras on UK motorways with a sign saying something along the lines of "Traffic Camera Not working"

Is there a reason why they put up this notice? If there was no notice they drivers might believe the camera was working and regulate their speed. Having the notice means that drivers can go faster.

I suppose there must be a law behind this but I wonder what the purpose behind it is.

Comment: Well, a truly clever police department would put the signs up on cameras that *were* working.....

Comment: I imagine the intent is to warn you that the next stretch of road is unsupervised and signs may not be able to give you heads up of a traffic jam or accident. Unless you have reason to believe otherwise I would assume traffic camera = monitoring, speed camera = enforcement.

Comment: Different agencies put up cameras next to UK roads, and 'traffic cameras' operated by the Highways Agency are used to manage traffic flow, and help monitor accidents and incidents on major roads. They are simply used for observation and aren't equipped with speed radars or number plate recognition systems. The notice is warning you to be alert and drive carefully (like you should anyway). Other types are operated by the police and used to monitor speed infractions, driving in bus lanes, uninsured or untaxed vehicle use, etc.